# Optional Login Spring + JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I try to create optional login you may can login by(username or phone number or email) in Java Spring and I have done it like this but it didn't work I searched a lot about it but with no answer and I pretty sure there is a way to do that.

this is the code as following:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;

   @Override
   if(loadUserByUsername(String username)){
          public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
             User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
             if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
             }
             return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
           }
   } elseif(loadUserByUsername(String phone)){
          public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String phone) {
                User user = userRepository.findByUsername(phone);
                if (user == null) {
                throw new PhoneNotFoundException(phone);
          }
          return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
   } elseif(loadUserByUsername(String email)){
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {
                User user = userRepository.findByUsername(email);
                if (user == null) {
                     throw new EmailNotFoundException(email);
                }
                return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
            }
   } else {
       return ex.CredentialNotFoundExptions;
   }
```

I do it like that to make the user have the option in login with the three ways but it keep giving me the error and didn't find the answer yet.
}

Comment: you code doesn't even compile, please provide code that compiles

Answer (score 2):

First of all: that's not how you override in Java. `@Override` should sit directly above a method declaration.

Second of all: you can't put any logic outside of a method (your if-else statement).

Third of all: your if-blocks (cases) don't actually acheive anything. For Java `String email` and `String phone` are the same thing, it's just a String. So the whole `if-else` doesn't make sense.

I'd just go with one, overriden `loadUserByUsername()`, and if you want to differantiate the login types, what comes to my mind first is regex, so that the declaration would become:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) {
    if (login.matches("(.*)@(.*).(.*)") {
        // email logic
    } else if (login.matches("[0-9]+") {
        // phone logic
    } else {
        // username logic
    }
}
```

It's just my first idea, for sure you could implement it in a better way. Also, the regex patterns are not ideal either, was just typing from the top of my head...

Comment: thanks a lot I do it like that and it's work perfectly

Comment: glad to help :) please mark it as a correct answer...

Comment: I try to but I couldn't I have earn 15 reputation first to do that privilege

Answer (score 0):

Beside the great answer above and the great way to make the code work I find this lesson it's explain everything about the optional login and how we can set it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B03UruvOl30

Every single  detail about jwt with spring-security and every single detail you couldn't understand about it.

You will find it in this video.